# Maven dependency get artefact from authentified Nexus

Tags: maven, dependencies, artifact

I want to download a Jar that is on a closed (authentified) Nexus. I want to do this via Maven, to be technology agnostic (it can work with Nexus or Artifcatory for example).

I found this intersting plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html, this works with an artifact that is on the central repository, or any "open" repository.

My command is:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:get -Dartifact=com.test.job:job-template:1.0.0:jar:jar-with-dependencies -Ddest=/tmp/test.jar -DremoteRepositories=http://nexus.test.local/nexus/content/repositories/test-releases/
```

I get an error: "Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized". Of course, I have to be authentified to get this artifact. How can I give my credentials to this command? My Maven settings.xml already contains the credentials for this local repository, but the command does not read these credentials (seems logical).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define server tag in your `~/.m2/settings.xml`

```
...
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>serverId</id>
      <username>login</username>
      <password>password</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
...
```

`serverId` is important you must use the same label in `remoteRepositories` properties, so you shoud run:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.4:get ... \
-DremoteRepositories=serverId::::http://nexus.test.local/...
```

Of course you can use any label as you wish for server/id

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I just have read the doc more carefully, it is written: "remoteRepositories: Repositories in the format id::[layout]::url or just url". My bad, thank you!